# Return the output of a command into an associative array

Tags: bash, shell-script, associative-array

I need to put the output of a command into an associative array.

For example:

```
dig mx +short google.com
```

Will return:

```
20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
40 alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
50 alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
10 aspmx.l.google.com.
30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

How can I create an associative array using the priorities (10,20,...) as the key and the record (aspmx.l.google.com.) as the value?

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one way to read that data into a bash associative array:

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
declare -A hosts
while IFS=" " read -r priority host ; do
  hosts["$priority"]="$host"
done < <(dig mx +short google.com)    

for priority in "${!hosts[@]}" ; do
  echo "$priority -> ${hosts[$priority]}"
done
```

**Output:**

```
20 -> alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
10 -> aspmx.l.google.com.
50 -> alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
40 -> alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
30 -> alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
```

Answer (score 2):

```
declare -A mx
eval $(dig mx +short google.com | sed "s/'//g; s/^/mx[/; s/ /]='/; s/$/';/")
```

First declare an associative array named `mx`, then execute `dig` and used `sed` to convert the output into associative array assignments, then `eval` that into the current shell. The `sed` command strips all single quotes, then wraps the variable assignment in, using single-quotes to quote the value.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think Stephen Rauch's solution (alongside chepner's comment) is great. But when it comes to [associative arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), I almost always use dictionaries in Python, not because I don't like Bash, but because they are (in my opinion) easier to work with in a higher level language.

Below is an example of usage in Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import subprocess
import os
import json

digDict = {}
tmpOut = open("tmpOut", "w")
output = subprocess.call(['dig', 'mx', '+short', 'google.com'], stdout=tmpOut)

# Fill the dictionary with the values we want
with open("tmpOut") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        digDict[line.split()[0]] = line.split()[1]

os.remove("tmpOut")

# Sort the dictionary by key
print("Sorted dictionary:")
for key in sorted(digDict):
    print(key + " -> " + digDict[key])

# Get a specific value based on key
print("Access value associated with key '10' (digDict[\"10\"]):")
print(digDict["10"])

# "Pretty print" the dictionary in json format
print("json format:")
print(json.dumps(digDict, sort_keys=True, indent=4))

# Saved the dictionary to file in json format
with open("digDict.json", "w") as fp:
    json.dump(digDict, fp, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

exit(0)
```

Execution:

```
./myDig.py 
Sorted dictionary:
10 -> aspmx.l.google.com.
20 -> alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
30 -> alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
40 -> alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.
50 -> alt4.aspmx.l.google.com.
Access value associated with key '10' (digDict["10"]):
aspmx.l.google.com.
json format:
{
    "10": "aspmx.l.google.com.",
    "20": "alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.",
    "30": "alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.",
    "40": "alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.",
    "50": "alt4.aspmx.l.google.com."
}
```

`cat digDict.json`:

```
{
    "10": "aspmx.l.google.com.",
    "20": "alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.",
    "30": "alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.",
    "40": "alt3.aspmx.l.google.com.",
    "50": "alt4.aspmx.l.google.com."
}
```

Again; the solution above in Bash is *great* (and upvoted by me). This is just another example in Python, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the internal field separator to separate the input into lines

```
 IFS="\n" read -ra ADDR <<< "$IN"
```